# Call method inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

`PageAdapter`:

```
class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
private String tabTitles[];

public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String[] categorie) {
    super(fm);
    PAGE_COUNT = categorie.length;
    tabTitles = new String[categorie.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < categorie.length; i++){
        tabTitles[i] = categorie[i];
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return Pagina.newInstance(position + 1);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    return tabTitles[position];
}
}
```

fragment activity :

```
public class Pagina extends Fragment {
private int mPage;
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

public static Pagina newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    Pagina fragment = new Pagina();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

// Inflate the fragment layout we defined above for this fragment
// Set the associated text for the title
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pagina, container, false);
    //TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    //tvTitle.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
    Log.e("STATO", "CI SIAMOOO");
    return view;
}

public void getSecondScrollView(String str){
    Log.e("ECCOLOO", "AVVIATO");
}

}
```

mainActivity :

```
public class PrincipaleActivity extends FragmentActivity{

public String[] categorie;

private String linguaApp = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
private Boolean linguaPresente = false;

private float scale;

private NetworkImageView imgProdotto;
private ViewPager pager;
private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;

private int screenWidth;
private int screenHeight;

private JSONObject dati;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principale);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    try {
        dati = new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra("DatiArticolo"));
        checkLingua();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ERRORE", "Errore durante il parsing del JSONObject o del checkLingua");
    }

    ((myMainScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollPrincipale)).setScrollingEnabled(false);

    creaCategorie();
    caricaImgProdotto();

    // Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),categorie));

    // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
    tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    setDimensioniSchermo();
    inizializzaPagina();

}

private void creaCategorie(){
    categorie = new String[dati.optJSONArray("categorie").length()];

    for (int h = 0; h < dati.optJSONArray("categorie").length(); h++){
        try {
            JSONObject temp = (JSONObject) dati.optJSONArray("categorie").get(h);
            categorie[h] = temp.optJSONObject("nome").optString(linguaApp);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void caricaImgProdotto(){
    imgProdotto = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProdotto);

    String url = "http://46.101.209.16/"+dati.optJSONObject("anagrafica").optJSONObject(linguaApp).optJSONObject("img").optString("path");
    Log.e("LINK IMG", url);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = MyImageLoader.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(imgProdotto, R.drawable.icona_flash, android.R.drawable .ic_dialog_alert));
    imgProdotto.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
}

private void checkLingua() throws JSONException {
    JSONArray valLingue = dati.optJSONObject("lingue").optJSONArray("lingueApp");


    for(int i = 0; i < valLingue.length(); i++){
        if(valLingue.get(i).equals(linguaApp)){
            linguaPresente = true;
        }
    }
    if (linguaPresente == false){
        linguaApp = dati.optJSONObject("lingue").optString("principale");
    }

    Log.e("Lingua Scelta ",linguaApp);
}

private void setDimensioniSchermo(){
    scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y;
}

private void inizializzaPagina(){
    imgProdotto.getLayoutParams().height = (screenWidth/3)*2;
    tabs.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(scale * 30);
    pager.getLayoutParams().height = screenHeight - (int)(scale * 30);
}

}
```

how can i call the method `getSecondScrollView` from my `SampleFragmentPagerAdapter` ?
i'm using this : https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip
i need the methods inside the fragment for get outside some views
sorry for bad english, i'm italian :D

Comment: You need to make interface for call that method

Comment: do you use this fragment inside of a viewPager?

Comment: Please, how is the error message?

Comment: yes, with this https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: show your code where you use SampleFragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: there are no errors , but do not know how to call the method

Comment: i have add the main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code in activity that have access to ViewPager :

```
 Pagina  fragment = (Pagina ) getSupportFragmentManager()
                  .findFragmentByTag( makeFragmentName(pager.getId(),page_index_of_pagina_fragment_inViewPager));
```

then call `fragment.getSecondScrollView("str");`

and this is `makeFragmentName` method that gets fragment name from adapter:

```
 private  String makeFragmentName(int viewPagerId, int index) {
      return "android:switcher:" + viewPagerId + ":" + index;
  }
```

**note** calls must be done after fragment completely loaded

Comment: error : cannot resolve method getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: i used inside a fragment use getFragmentManager() or geSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: runtime error : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void layout.Pagina.getSecondScrollView(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: getCurrentItem() i mean the index of pagina fragment you should use index of pagina fragment in view pager.

Comment: if i set 0 or 1 the error is the same. 
It may be the fact that the fragment had not yet been loaded ?

Comment: yes the problem is that! :) there is a function to override that is lunch when the fragments are loaded?

Comment: I used this call in viewpager on selected page changed event

Comment: Im with my phone on stackoverflow now, please edit my code to make it a better answer for helping some people else that may have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a callbacklistener, make `Pagina` implement an interface for example `PagerAdapterListener` which has the method `onGetSecondScrollView()`, like this:

```
public interface PagerAdapterListener {
   void onGetSecondScrollView(String str);
}
```

Then add a `PagerAdapterListener` to your `Adapter`'s constructor, so that your `Adapter` has a variable of the type `PagerAdapterListener` (`new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(..., ..., this)`) . When you need to call the `getSecondScrollView()` method just call the `onGetSecondScrollView()` method on the interface (which is actually your `Fragment`).

And ofcourse dont forget to implement the PagerAdapterListener and its onGetSecondScrollView() method like this:

```
public class Pagina extends Fragment implements PagerAdapterListener {

    @Override
    public void onGetSecondScrollView(String str) {
        getSecondScrollView(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with "Then add a PagerAdapterListener to your Adapter's constructor, so that your Adapter has a variable of the type PagerAdapterListener (new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(..., ..., this)) . "

Comment: Add a variable to your Adapter of the type PagerAdapterListener (the interface) and when creating the Adapter, give the instance of your fragment which implements the interface to the Adapter through its constructor (your constructor will look like: SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(var1, var2, this);